# How to redirect to page multiple times and update information on page with django

Tags: python, django, django-views, render

I am working on a web app. The webapp has a view in which a for loop runs and updates three lists with every iteration. The lengths of the lists are stored in a dictionary. I want to display the length of the lists on a template after every iteration. How do I do this? Here is my code so far

views.py

```
def update_lst(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       lst1, lst2, lst3 = [], [], []

       for i in range(10):
           lst1.append(i+1)
           lst2.append(i+2)
           lst3.append(i+3)

           context = {'length1':len(lst1), 'length2':len(lst2), 'length3':len(lst3)}
           render(request, 'details.html', context)

        return redirect('index.html')

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

details.html

```
<h1>Extracting details</h1>
<p>{{length1}}: length of list1</p>
<p>{{length2}}: length of list2</p>
<p>{{length3}}: length of list3</p>
```

Right now the render function inside the for loop does not execute. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Inseet the `context` in the `return`

```
return redirect('index.html', context)
```

Your code `return` `index.html` without any `context`

Answer (score 0):

Two things I think are a problem, first is you're missing `return` keyword in front of your `render` statement.  Second, your indentation is off.  Try this:

```
def update_lst(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       lst1, lst2, lst3 = [], [], []

       for i in range(10):
           lst1.append(i+1)
           lst2.append(i+2)
           lst3.append(i+3)

       context = {'length1':len(lst1), 'length2':len(lst2), 'length3':len(lst3)}

       # you code is missing this "return" keyword here
       return render(request, 'details.html', context)

    return redirect('index.html')
```

Comment: The render function is outside the for loop. How will this update the page after every iteration?